# Verwendung von das/dass

Tags: pronoun

Mit ein paar Freunden stecke ich gerade in einer Diskussion fest, warum in einer bestimmten Situation "das" und nicht "dass" zu verwenden ist. Abgesehen von der Person, die den fraglichen Satz geschrieben hat, sind wir uns alle einig, dass "das" richtig ist. Der anderen Person erklären, *warum* das der Fall ist, kann aber keiner so richtig - wir "wissen" das alle intuitiv, ohne die Regel konkret erklären zu können.

Der fragliche Satz, um den es geht, ist folgender [sic]:

> Leben heißt rückwärts Nebel, dass ist der Grund, warum wir nie durchblicken.

Folgende (unserer Meinung nach grammatikalisch korrekte) Varianten sind uns eingefallen:

> - Leben heißt rückwärts Nebel. Das ist der Grund, warum wir nie durchblicken.
> - Leben heißt rückwärts Nebel, was der Grund ist, warum wir nie durchblicken.
> - Dass Leben rückwärts Nebel heißt, ist der Grund, warum wir nie durchblicken.
> - Der Grund, warum wir nie durchblicken, ist, dass Leben rückwärts Nebel heißt.

**Die eigentliche Frage konnten wir aber nicht zufriedenstellend beantworten: warum genau ist im ursprünglichen Beispiel "dass" falsch?**

Comment: Anmerkung: ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob das "das" im korrigierten Beispielsatz #1 zu [tag:demonstrative-pronouns] oder zu [tag:relative-pronouns] zählt, daher habe ich mal den Standard-[tag:pronouns]-Tag verwendet.

Answer (score 1):

Aus zwei Gründen kann der Teil nach dem Komma kein von der Konjunktion *dass* eingeleiteter Nebensatz sein:

1. Das Prädikat müsste am Ende stehen, wenn es sich um einen Nebensatz handelte: *…, dass der Grund **ist**, warum wir nie durchblicken.*
2. Wie man bei Punkt (1) sieht, würde dem Nebensatz dann ein Subjekt fehlen, weil dieses ja eigentlich *das* ist.

---

*Das* ist hier ein substantivisch gebrauchtes Demonstrativpronomen, das sich auf den ersten Hauptsatz bezieht und selbst Subjekt vom zweiten *Haupt*satz ist. Das Komma ist hier etwas unglücklich. Besser wäre ein Punkt wie in eurem ersten Vorschlag, ein Semikolon oder ein Gedankenstrich.

*Dass* hingegen ist eine unterordnende Konjunktion, die entweder einen Konsekutivsatz oder einen Inhaltssatz einleiten würde.  Ein Konsekutivsatz gibt eine Folge an (dann kann *dass* durch *sodass* ersetzt werden), ein Inhaltssatz folgt zum Beispiel auf *wissen, dass …*, *sagen, dass …* oder auch *wetten, dass …*.

Answer (score 0):

*Das* lässt sich in Gedanken immer durch *welches*, *jenes* oder *dieses* ersetzen ohne dass der Satz seinen Sinn verliert und das ist auch bei diesem Beispiel der Fall:

> Leben heißt rückwärts Nebel, **jenes** ist der Grund, warum wir nie
>   durchblicken.

Deswegen ist *das* in diesem Fall die richtige Schreibweise.

An dieser Stelle sei auch noch die dafür hilfreiche Seite [das-dass.de](https://www.das-dass.de/#regeln) erwähnt.

Comment: Müssten in diesem Fall "Leben heißt rückwärts Nebel" und der Rest des Beispiels nicht auch durch einen Punkt, Gedankenstrich o. Ä. getrennt sein? Andernfalls klingt der Satz für mich sehr merkwürdig.

Comment: Ich meine "jenes" bezieht sich normalerweise auf ein zweites: "Fußball und Handball sind Massensportarten, dieses mehr, jenes weniger". Daher wäre hier "dieses" richtig.

Comment: @PixelMaster Stilistisch besser, finde ich auch. Aber die Konstruktion ist eine recht interessante, und kann, denke ich, als eine Art Cleftsatz mit einer Anführung im Gleichsetzungsnominativ aufgesst werden (von _Der Grund ist, Leben heißt rückwärts Nebel_ -- vgl. _Hans schlägt den Hund_ ~> _Den Hund, das schlägt Hans_). _Das_ ist in dem Fall einfach einfach anaphorisch. Gefühlsmäßig nahe an einem absoluten Nominativ (_Leben heißt Neben -- das ist der Grund_).